# Install AMD \ Nvidia GPU Extensions during AVD Session Host provisioning?

Tags: azure

I am trying to find out if it is possible to install either the AMD or NVidia GPU extensions when provisioning new hosts via the Azure Virtual Desktop (AVD) wizard, I can see at the bottom of the wizard that there's an Custom Configuration Script URL but it doesn't seem to like direct JSON ARM templates to deploy the extension, here is an example of what I tried to include: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/durrante/AVD/main/Extensions/Deploy_NVIDIA_GPU.json

I'm not sure if the section in the AVD wizard is even capable of the above, but my end goal is to deploy the extensions during AVD provisioning rather than manually installing the GPU drivers in master images, has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> my end goal is to deploy the extensions during AVD provisioning rather than manually installing the GPU drivers in master images, has anyone got any ideas?

You can install the **NVIDIA GPU** drivers for windows extensions when provisioning new **AVD** hosts via the portal.

Follow the steps below to install the Windows extensions when provisioning new AVD hosts via the portal.

1. Upload the below [script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-windows.md#powershell) to your storage account.

```
Install-Module Az.Compute -Force
Import-Module Az.Compute
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "Resourcegroup-Name" -VMName "VM-Name" -Location "East Us" -Publisher "Microsoft.HpcCompute" -ExtensionName "NvidiaGpuDriverWindows" -ExtensionType "NvidiaGpuDriverWindows" -TypeHandlerVersion 1.4
```

2. Copy the `URL` of the powershell script once upload the powershell script.

[image]

3. Add the `PowerShell` script path that you copied from storage to the **Custom Configuration** option when creating an **Azure Virtual Desktop**

[image]

> Note: If you create a host pool with the name 'X,' you can specify the VM Name as 'X.

Once **AVD** provisioning is complete, the `extension` is successfully created as shown below

[image]

Reference: Extension type: [NvidiaGpuDriverWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-windows#arm-template)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, daft question, but in the powershell script, do I need to specify a vm / resource group name? I was hoping that this script could dynamically pick up those variables from the avd wizard, resource group name isn't really an issue but I suspect the vm name will be as there could be if deploying multiple VMs as I'd need to determine what the vm names will be in advance. Any ideas? I didn't quite understand your note either about host pool name, could you elaborate? Thanks again.

Comment: Here is the script to retrieve all VMs and run the script on each VM without entering the details.$resourceGroupName = "your resourcegroup-name"
    #Get the list of VMs in the resource group
    $vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    #Install the Extension in All VMS
    foreach ($vm in $vmList) {
        $vmName = $vm.Name
        Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VMName $vmName -Location "East Us" -Publisher "Microsoft.HpcCompute" -ExtensionName "NvidiaGpuDriverWindows" -ExtensionType "NvidiaGpuDriverWindows" -TypeHandlerVersion 1.4
    }

Comment: Hi again, so I uploaded this script into a storage account: https://stlcmaibuks001.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/Install_NVididaGPUExtension.ps1, however, when ran via AVD, the following error occurred: Get-AzVM : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to \r\naccess an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.\r\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\\1.10.15\\Downloads\\0\\Install_NVididaGPUExtension.ps1:9.

Am I missing something? thanks

Comment: Create an Service prinicipal and assign role on Virtual Machine or Subscription scope and authenticate via Service prinicipal, connect-Azconnect won't work in this scenario.